# Is "order by" clause in DBSCAN necessary?

Tags: postgis, clustering

In the following code, is "order by" necessary for the **DBScan** function or is it adding an overhead for no reason?

```
clustering as(
SELECT row_id, city_id , imei, speed, points_geom ,time_created, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(points_geom,5243) ,eps := 100, minPoints := 150) over (partition by city_id ORDER BY row_id) 
  AS cluster_id FROM subset_cr 
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessary to obtain a correct result. But because DBSCAN may have multiple valid solutions for a given set of inputs, the ordering may be necessary to obtain a stable result (i.e., the same clusters are returned every time the function is called on the same inputs.)

Comment: Thanks! would you recommend using it, generally speaking? I really have to speed up query execution so I don't quite like it at the moment!

Comment: Do you require stable clusters? I'd be really surprised if the sorting made any difference in query execution time.